# How to drag and drop a folder on other folder has same name of folder without losing existing files

Tags: finder, osx-mavericks

I would like to know how to drag and drop a folder on other folder has same name of folder without losing existing files.

**For example:**

I have same name of file under Folder1 like below. then I move folder1 on Desktop to Documents then will be replaced the folder on Documents. So, File2 will be gone atuaclly the folder will be replaced with Folder1 of Desktop.

- Documents/Folder1/File2
- Desktop/Folder1/File3

I would like to have like below result.

**Expected results:**

Documents/Folder1/File2 and File3.

i'm fine even if it's handled by script. please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> while dragging the folder onto its target. This will bring up a new dialog that allows you to merge the folders:

[image]

After merging, the `Folder1` will contain both files. Note that the original folder will still exist at its source location—the files will only be copied, not removed.

Comment: ♦, Thank you for the information and kind advice. It worked!